# How do I use Plain Text Field in URL Format?

Tags: templating, url, format

I'm creating an events system & I want to include the venue in the url of the event along with the event name.

For now the venue name is just stored using a plain text field.

Is there an easy way in craft to convert a string & slugify it? Could I use any filter I add to Craft? Can I do it without a plugin of some sort?

I've tried the following

```
{ (eventVenue ? "-" ~ eventVenue | lower | replace(' ', '-') | replace('/[^\w]/','')) }
```

along with using Twig PCRE

```
{ (eventVenue ? "-" ~ eventVenue | lower | preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/') ) }
```

Both of which give the error `Expecting name or number`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Slugify](http://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/slugify) plugin has a Twig filter that should do what you're looking for.